prolog rule_based expert system
am a beginner in prolong, i want to develop a rule_based expert system that suggests best fit and next fit job for user based on his scores in some tests and skills . here is the knowledge base :
% Facts about job scores
score_for_job('Snowflake\'s Cloud Data Warehouse', 'Business Intelligence Developer', 8, 15).
score_for_job('Business Intelligence', 'Business Intelligence Developer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Business Intelligence _ SAS Data Sets Overview', 'Business Intelligence Developer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Analytics Quiz', 'Business Intelligence Developer', 7, 15).
score_for_job('Data Warehousing', 'Business Intelligence Developer', 8, 15).

score_for_job('Data Analytics Quiz', 'Data Analyst', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Visualization', 'Data Analyst', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Mining Trivia Quiz', 'Data Analyst', 7, 15).
score_for_job('Data Warehousing', 'Data Analyst', 7, 15).

score_for_job('ETL Assessment For ETL Developers', 'Data Engineer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Snowflake\'s Cloud Data Warehouse', 'Data Engineer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Warehousing', 'Data Engineer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Visualization', 'Data Engineer', 8, 15).

score_for_job('Data Mining Trivia Quiz', 'Data Scientist', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Visualization', 'Data Scientist', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Analytics Quiz', 'Data Scientist', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Warehousing', 'Data Scientist', 10, 15).

score_for_job('ETL Assessment For ETL Developers', 'ETL Developer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Data Warehousing', 'ETL Developer', 10, 15).
score_for_job('Snowflake\'s Cloud Data Warehouse', 'ETL Developer', 8, 15).

% Facts about required skills for each job
required_skills_for_job('Business Intelligence Developer', [power_bi, ssrs, ssas, sql, data_warehousing]).
required_skills_for_job('Data Analyst', [data_analysis, data_visualization, communication, analytical_skills]).
required_skills_for_job('Data Engineer', [python, java, sql, etl, data_analytics]).
required_skills_for_job('Data Scientist', [python, data_science, machine_learning, data_visualization, data_analytics]).
required_skills_for_job('ETL Developer', [etl, sql, data_warehousing, data_analysis]).


and here is the rule base :
 % Rule for recommending jobs based on quiz scores and skills
recommend_jobs(QuizScores, Skills, RecommendedJobs) :-
    % Collect job data
    findall((Job, MatchedQuizzes, MatchedSkills, NumSkills, NumQuizzes), (
        % Collect quizzes that match for the job
        findall(Quiz, (member((Quiz, Score), QuizScores),
                       score_for_job(Quiz, Job, Min, Max),
                       Score >= Min,
                       Score =< Max), Quizzes),
        list_to_set(Quizzes, MatchedQuizzes),
        % Collect skills that match for the job
        required_skills_for_job(Job, RequiredSkills),
        findall(ReqSkill, (member(ReqSkill, RequiredSkills),
                           member(ReqSkill, Skills)), MatchedSkills),
        length(MatchedSkills, NumSkills),
        length(MatchedQuizzes, NumQuizzes),
        % Only include jobs where we have matched quizzes or skills
        (NumQuizzes > 0 ; NumSkills > 0)
    ), AllJobs),

    % Sort jobs by number of matched skills and quizzes
    predsort(compare_jobs, AllJobs, SortedJobs),

    % Return best and next fit jobs
    (   SortedJobs = [(BestFitJob, BestMatchedQuizzes, BestMatchedSkills, BestNumSkills, BestNumQuizzes) | RestJobs]
    ->  (   RestJobs = [(NextFitJob, NextMatchedQuizzes, NextMatchedSkills, NextNumSkills, NextNumQuizzes) | _]
        ->  RecommendedJobs = [best_fit(BestFitJob, BestMatchedQuizzes, BestMatchedSkills, BestNumSkills, BestNumQuizzes),
                               next_fit(NextFitJob, NextMatchedQuizzes, NextMatchedSkills, NextNumSkills, NextNumQuizzes)]
        ;   RecommendedJobs = [best_fit(BestFitJob, BestMatchedQuizzes, BestMatchedSkills, BestNumSkills, BestNumQuizzes)]
        )
    ;   RecommendedJobs = []
    ).

% Custom comparison for sorting jobs based on skills and quizzes
compare_jobs(Delta, (_, _, _, NumSkills1, NumQuizzes1), (_, _, _, NumSkills2, NumQuizzes2)) :-
    % Compare based on the number of skills first
    compare(SkillDelta, NumSkills2, NumSkills1),
    (SkillDelta = (=)
    ->  % If the number of skills is the same, compare based on the number of quizzes
        compare(QuizDelta, NumQuizzes2, NumQuizzes1),
        Delta = QuizDelta
    ;   Delta = SkillDelta).

% Use this directive to suppress warnings about non-contiguous predicates
:- discontiguous score_for_job/4, required_skills_for_job/2.

and there is this python code that represents the interface :
import json
from swiplserver import PrologMQI, PrologThread

def load_scores(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        scores = json.load(file)
    return scores

def find_best_fit_jobs(prolog_thread, scores):
    quiz_scores = [(quiz, score) for quiz, score in scores.items()]
    skills = ['python', 'data_science', 'machine_learning', 'data_visualization', 'data_analytics']

    query = f"recommend_jobs({quiz_scores}, {skills}, RecommendedJobs)"
    result = prolog_thread.query(query)
    return result[0]['RecommendedJobs'] if result else []

def parse_job_info(job_info):
    job = job_info['args'][0]  # Job name
    matched_quizzes = job_info['args'][1]  # List of matched quizzes
    matched_skills = job_info['args'][2]  # List of matched skills
    skill_count = job_info['args'][3]  # Skill count
    return {
        "job": job,
        "matched_quizzes": matched_quizzes,
        "matched_skills": matched_skills,
        "skill_count": skill_count
    }

def explain_job_choice(recommended_jobs):
    job_explanations = []
    for job_info in recommended_jobs:
        try:
            explanation = parse_job_info(job_info)
            job_explanations.append(explanation)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error parsing job_info: {job_info}. Error: {e}")
    return job_explanations

def fetch_jobs():
    scores = load_scores('user_scores.json')
    with PrologMQI() as mqi:
        with mqi.create_thread() as prolog_thread:
            prolog_thread.query("consult('rules.pl')")
            recommended_jobs = find_best_fit_jobs(prolog_thread, scores)
            job_data = {}

            if recommended_jobs:
                explanations = explain_job_choice(recommended_jobs)
                if explanations:
                    job_data["best_fit"] = explanations[0]
                    if len(explanations) > 1:
                        job_data["next_fit"] = explanations[1]
                    else:
                        job_data["next_fit"] = None

    return job_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    job_data = fetch_jobs()
    for key in ["best_fit", "next_fit"]:
        if job_data.get(key):
            print(f"\n{key.replace('_', ' ').title()}: {job_data[key]['job']}")
            print(f"  Matched quizzes: {', '.join(job_data[key]['matched_quizzes'])}")
            print(f"  Matched skills: {', '.join(job_data[key]['matched_skills'])}")
            print(f"  Skill count: {job_data[key]['skill_count']}")
        else:
            print(f"\n{key.replace('_', ' ').title()}: None")


and have this testing case:
Scores:
{
    "Snowflake's Cloud Data Warehouse": 8,
    "Business Intelligence": 7,
    "Data Analytics Quiz": 7,
    "Data Warehousing": 8,
    "Data Visualization": 8
}


Skills:
skills = ['python', 'data_science', 'machine_learning', 'data_visualization', 'data_analytics']


Expected Result:

Best Fit: Data Scientist

Matched quizzes: Data Visualization, Data Analytics Quiz, Data Warehousing
Matched skills: python, data_science, machine_learning, data_visualization, data_analytics
Skill count: 5


Next Fit: Data Engineer

Matched quizzes: Data Warehousing, Snowflake's Cloud Data Warehouse
Matched skills: python, sql, etl, data_analytics
Skill count: 4



but i don't get the expected values
i get this result :
Best Fit: Data Scientist
Matched quizzes: Data Analytics Quiz, Data Warehousing, Data Visualization
Matched skills: python, data_science, machine_learning, data_visualization, data_analytics
Skill count: 5
Next Fit: Data Engineer
Matched quizzes: Data Analytics Quiz, Data Warehousing, Data Visualization
Matched skills: python, data_analytics
Skill count: 2

Instead of (NumQuizzes > 0 ; NumSkills > 0) could use: NumQuizzes + NumSkills > 0

nothing changed

The maths in NumQuizzes + NumSkills > 0 prevents the choicepoint in (NumQuizzes > 0 ; NumSkills > 0), so is preferable code.

got it . how about the whole code . I don't know where is the problem . what should I do?

Simple answer: debug your own code - don't fall into the common trap of continuing to add complexity until you're unable to understand your own code. Simplify the code, break it down into understandable chunks and then debug those chunks. If still confused, produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , which people would be much more inclined to help with.
